# How to set the width of the children of GridLayout to equal size and make them evenly distributed?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a GridLayout with 3 ImageViews as children. The columnCount is set to 3 and they should be evenly distributed horizontally. This is the XML:

```
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_contact_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_empresa_facebook_contact_id"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_empresa_whatsapp_contact_id"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_empresa_call_id"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

    </GridLayout>
```

Instead of having 3 images with equal width, fitting perfectly in the horizontal space, this is what I get (The first image is huge and the other ones cannot be seen):

[image]

How can I evenly distribute the grid horizontal content? There are 3 columns, one for each image, and the grid's width is matching the one of the parent. Also, it doesn't work if I remove the weights. The size of the image views is irrelevant, they should adjust to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GridView`, as posted, has only one row. In this case, I would just use a `LinearLayout` instead:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/info_contact_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_empresa_facebook_contact_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_empresa_whatsapp_contact_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info_empresa_call_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks. Didn't use a LinearLayout because I thought that the Grid would give me that (I mean, by definition the size of its children are not set manually). I'm still curious on how to make that work using a GridLayout though.

Comment: @EricsonWillians My personal experience is that `GridView` is always a hassle to use and almost anything would be better (a stack of `LinearLayout`s, a `FlexboxLayout`, a `ConstraintLayout`, etc).